# Create string of month year in order by date

Tags: sql-server

My existing query is:

```
SELECT @str = coalesce(@str + ']' + ', ', '') + '[' + monthyear
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ( monthyear), ExpectedDate
      FROM table) s
order by ExpectedDate
```

I need to bring unique `monthyear` string in order by its date

```
ExpectedDate    monthyear
2015-11-01       Nov-15
2015-11-01       Nov-15
2015-11-01       Nov-15
2015-11-01       Nov-15
2015-11-01       Nov-15
2015-11-01       Nov-15
2015-11-01       Nov-15
2015-11-01       Nov-15
2015-11-01       Nov-15
2015-11-01       Nov-15
2015-12-01       Dec-15
2015-12-01       Dec-15
2015-12-01       Dec-15
2015-12-01       Dec-15
2015-12-01       Dec-15
2015-12-01       Dec-15
2015-12-01       Dec-15
2015-12-01       Dec-15
2015-12-02       Dec-15
2015-12-30       Dec-15
2016-01-01       Jan-16
2016-01-01       Jan-16
2016-01-01       Jan-16
2016-01-01       Jan-16
2016-01-01       Jan-16
2016-01-01       Jan-16
2016-01-01       Jan-16
2016-01-01       Jan-16
2016-01-01       Jan-16
2016-01-01       Jan-16
2016-01-01       Jan-16
2016-01-01       Jan-16
2016-01-01       Jan-16
2016-01-01       Jan-16
2016-01-04       Jan-16
2016-01-04       Jan-16
2016-01-04       Jan-16
2016-01-04       Jan-16
2016-02-01       Feb-16
2016-02-01       Feb-16
2016-02-01       Feb-16
2016-02-01       Feb-16
2016-02-01       Feb-16
2016-02-01       Feb-16
2016-02-01       Feb-16
2016-02-01       Feb-16
2016-02-01       Feb-16
2016-03-01       Mar-16
2016-03-01       Mar-16
2016-03-01       Mar-16
2016-03-01       Mar-16
2016-03-01       Mar-16
2016-03-01       Mar-16
2016-03-01       Mar-16
2016-04-01       Apr-16
2016-04-01       Apr-16
2016-04-01       Apr-16
2016-04-01       Apr-16
2016-04-01       Apr-16
2016-06-01       Jun-16
2016-06-01       Jun-16
2016-07-01       Jul-16
2016-10-01       Oct-16
2016-10-01       Oct-16
2016-12-01       Dec-16
2016-12-30       Dec-16
```

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: and your sample result like?

Comment: [Nov2015], [Dec2015], [Dec2015], [Dec2015], [Jan2016], [Jan2016], [Feb2016], [Mar2016], [Apr2016], [Jun2016], [Jul2016], [Oct2016], [Dec2016], [Dec2016]

Comment: no help it's giving nested query error... can you show a sample

Comment: do you want the distinct  monthyear or all of them ?

Comment: I have a really nice way of getting the solution in 1 row as described. I don't see how this was a copy. Voting for reopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XML PATH

```
DECLARE @t table(ExpectedDate date, monthdate char(8))
INSERT @t values
('2015-11-01', 'Nov-2015'),
('2015-11-01', 'Nov-2015'),
('2015-12-01', 'Dec-2015'),
('2015-12-01', 'Dec-2015'),
('2016-01-01', 'Jan-2016')

SELECT 
    STUFF(( 
        SELECT ',[' + STUFF(monthdate,4,1, '') + ']'
        FROM @t t1 
        GROUP BY ExpectedDate, monthdate
        ORDER BY ExpectedDate
        for xml path(''), type 
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') [values]
```

Result:

```
[Nov2015],[Dec2015],[Jan2016]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MonthName()` and `Year()` inbuilt functions provided my `MySQL`.

```
MonthName(ExpectedDate), Year(ExpectedDate)
```

Ex: `Month(2016-02-01)` with give you `Februray`

Then you can concat the results.

Comment: I am already making mothyear from that... (Left(Datename(month,ExpectedDate),3)+ Datename(year,ExpectedDate)) as monthyear into #temptable

Answer (score 0):

If `monthyear` column is `varchar` type, you can try this:

```
SELECT '[' + SUBSTRING(monthyear, 1, 3) + CAST(YEAR(PAY_DATE) AS VARCHAR) + ']'
FROM Your_Table
```

If `monthyear` column is `date` or `datetime` type, you can try this:

```
SELECT '[' + SUBSTRING(DateName(month, DateAdd(month, MONTH(Pay_Date), 0) - 1 ), 1, 3)
           + CAST(YEAR(PAY_DATE) AS VARCHAR) + ']'
FROM Your_Table
```